# How to fix this error " attempt to use zero length variable" in (r markdown file) when creating a factor variable for a categorical variable

Tags: r

demo <- demo %>%
mutate(
sex_f = factor(sex,
levels = c(
"male", "female", "NA"
)
)
)

Comment: Your code seems fine.  Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` to understand the issue

Comment: Thanks Akrun for responding. I was able to actually figure when creating a reproducible example. Posted the answer below. Welcome for suggestions.

Comment: Your example with code is working fine for me

Comment: Great!. Yes it did for me too. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
demo <- tibble::tribble(

~id, ~sex, ~dob,
"001", "male", "1943-03-04",
"002", "female", "1951-02-07",
"003", "male", "1962-01-24",
"004", "NA", "1985-05-26"
)
```

demo <- demo %>%
mutate(sex_f = factor(sex, levels = c("male", "feamle", "other")))